# how to accesss Json for numbered elements

Tags: javascript, json, object

My JSON object has numbers as key for some nested objects. Not able to access these elements using .(dot) notation

example code
{
"1" : "Done"
}

assuming the object name is JSON 
JSON.1 access method is not working

Error
Unexpected number

Comment: x[1] where x is the name of the javascript variable that contains the parse JSON as a javascript object

Answer (score 0):

Dot notation does not work with all keys, but you could always try like that: `JSON["1"]`, or even `JSON[1]` for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation:

```js
const obj = { "1" : "Done" };
console.log(obj[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use [dot notation<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) to access numbered elements in a JavaScript object.

> The property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number.

You must choose a different form of access, most commonly in this situation would be [Bracket notation<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
JSON[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using adding double quotes while using number.
On which language you are trying to run.

On Javascript below will work both with double quotes and without quotes .

```
<script>
    var data = '{"1":"Done"}';
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    document.write (json[1]); // without double quotes
    document.write  (json["1"]);// with double quotes
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [] for this case instead of dot operator.

```
var tes = { "test1" : { "3" : "Done", "char" : "TODO"}}

for(var property in tes.test1) {
   //console.log(property)
   console.log(tes.test1[property])
}
```

```js
var tes = { "test1" : { "3" : "Done", "char" : "TODO"}}

for(var property in tes.test1) {
   //console.log(property)
   console.log(tes.test1[property])
}
```